# How to get the id of the last added div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a comment system where when a user posts a comment, it gets added on top of the others. I'm using ajax. Now, I wish to get the id of the last added comment div in the success function of the ajax so that I can scroll down to it. How should I get the id?

I tried this:

```
alert($("div.take:last").attr('id'));
```

But it shows "undefined".

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried before? show some code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: Try https://api.jquery.com/last/ or https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/ which you could have found yourself

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)..

Comment: $(".take").last().attr('id');

Comment: @Bharatsoni thanks! But it still shows undefined

Comment: What is the common name of class of all the comment divs ? Did you define the id attributes for the div or not ?

Comment: You can use random unique ID for each div

Comment: @Bharatsoni, class of all comment divs is "comment_div" and yeah I have defined the id attributes for the div

Comment: $(".comment_div").last().attr('id');

Comment: Thanks you so much, @Bharatsoni!!! It worked!!!! :)